# Enable Camera and microphone permissions for react native webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking, react-native-webview

I am building a react native application in which I have to hit a URL to let user for a video call ,but when I open that URL in Webview I cant access camera and microphone of device(both a\Android and IOS) required for call and I can't open the URL in browser using linking because I can't let user know that URL because if they know URL they can call anytime using that URL but I don't want that.